# Error when compiling app in Android 9.0 using SQLite.Net-PCL [Xamarin.Android]

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-9.0-pie, sqlite.net

I am trying to compile my application that requires a comunications with a local service, which is SQLite, I (and from the start of my long project) have been using [**SQLite.Net-PCL** plugin](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL), but when compiling my app into android 9.0 versions, it throws me the following error:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: '/system/lib64/libsqlite.so assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)'
```

I have been searching about the error, and I found what I consider "Not verified solutions" since they don't prove why something is correct, in this case, people that answer to this problem give the answer of: "replace the SQLite.Net-PCL plugin for the sqlite.net-pcl one" but why? is there a problem using SQLite.Net-PCL on current versions of android, and how can I avoid this error using the current plugin (SQLite.Net-PCL)?

**Note**: this only happens in Android 9.0 (which I have proved) and on other versions such as Android 6.0 is everything ok.

Comment: You should be using the org. version that is maintained and has the correct SQLite dependencies : https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net

Comment: the version you are using is not being maintained and has not been updated in years